Cython: Protecting a cdef class if __init__ is not called
I'm wrapping some Fortran/C codes with Cython. The __init__ method of my cdef class allocates some memory in C. I believe that this memory allocation has to happen in the __init__ method instead of the __cinit__ method because the allocation depends on inputs to __init__ (e.g. an input file).
However, there is potential for memory errors, because of inheritance. A class that inherits the Cython class could fail to call the parent __init__ method, thus not allocating needed memory in C.
I am wondering if the code below is a good workaround for this problem. Here, I define a __getattribute__ and __setattr__, which checks to make sure __init__ has been called, and throws an error if it has not.
Complete example:
Some C code to wrap
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct
{
  int n;
  double *data;
  int count;
} Example;

void example_allocate(void **ptr)
{
  *ptr = (void *) malloc(sizeof(Example));
}

void example_deallocate(void **ptr)
{
  Example *p = (Example *) *ptr;
  free(p);
}

void example_create(void **ptr, int *n)
{
  Example *p = (Example *) *ptr;
  p->count = 3;
  p->n = *n;
  p->data = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*p->n);
  for (int i = 0; i < p->n; i++){
    p->data[i] = i;
  }
}

void example_sum_data(void **ptr, double *val)
{
  Example *p = (Example *) *ptr;

  *val = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < p->n; i++){
    *val += p->data[i];
  }
}

void example_count_get(void **ptr, int *count)
{
  Example *p = (Example *) *ptr;
  *count = p->count;
}

void example_count_set(void **ptr, int *count)
{
  Example *p = (Example *) *ptr;
  p->count = *count;
}

Cython wrapper:
from libcpp cimport bool as cbool
from cpython.object cimport PyObject_GenericSetAttr

cdef extern void example_allocate(void **ptr);
cdef extern void example_deallocate(void **ptr)
cdef extern void example_create(void **ptr, int *n)
cdef extern void example_sum_data(void **ptr, double *val)
cdef extern void example_count_get(void **ptr, int *count)
cdef extern void example_count_set(void **ptr, int *count)

cdef class Example:

  cdef void *_ptr
  cdef cbool _init_called

  def __cinit__(self):
    self._init_called = False
    example_allocate(&self._ptr)

  def __dealloc__(self):
    example_deallocate(&self._ptr)

  def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if not self._init_called:
      raise Exception('The "__init__" method of Example has not been called.')
    return super().__getattribute__(name)

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if not self._init_called:
      raise Exception('The "__init__" method of Example has not been called.')
    PyObject_GenericSetAttr(self, name, value)

  def __init__(self, int n):           
    self._init_called = True
    example_create(&self._ptr, &n)

  def sum_data(self):
    cdef double val;
    example_sum_data(&self._ptr, &val)
    return val

  property count:
    def __get__(self):
      cdef int val
      example_count_get(&self._ptr, &val)
      return val
    def __set__(self, int val):
      example_count_set(&self._ptr, &val)


Python example usage
e1 = Example(10)
a = e1.sum_data()
print(a)

class ExampleChild(Example):
    def __init__(self, n):
        # forgets to call init
        pass

e2 = ExampleChild(9)
a = e2.do_stuff() # Raises exception 
print(a)


As this is working code, I'd suggest posting this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

__cinit__ can take arguments so I'm unclear why you can't use it.
